# Find specific element by class withing an object already stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a **HTML** like this:

```
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item active">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
```

and a **jQuery** variable that keeps the `.item` elements :

```
var $items = $('.item');
```

**Question:** Is there a simple way to find the `text()` of the element with additional `active` class, using the `$items` variable?

I know I can loop through the elements of `$items` but it seems like an overkill. Can I e.g. use `.find()` in some way on the object I already have to locate the `active` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```
var $act = $items.filter('.active')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method

```
 var active_items = $items.filter(".active");
```

and you can get the text of the active_item by using

```
   var text_of_active_item= active_items.first().text();
```